# Moment.js: Translation doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Does anyone have experience with translation in moment.js?

I'm using it with "pickaday.js". It works fine in Chrome, and my days are translated in the language I choosed, for example in "german" it's translated as

```
Donnerstag, 19. März 2015
```

But in firefox it's translated as:

```
Thu Mar 26 2015
```

Relevant source code:

```
var moment_de = {
            months : "Januar_Februar_März_April_Mai_Juni_Juli_August_September_Oktober_November_Dezember".split("_"),
            monthsShort : "Jan._Feb._März_Apr._Mai_Juni_Juli._Aug._Sept._Okt._Nov._Dez.".split("_"),
            weekdays : "Sonntag_Montag_Dienstag_Mittwoch_Donnerstag_Freitag_Samstag".split("_"),
            weekdaysShort : "So._Mo._Di._Mi._Do._Fr._Sa.".split("_"),
            weekdaysMin : "So_Mo_Di_Mi_Do_Fr_Sa".split("_"),
            longDateFormat : {
                LT : "HH:mm",
                LTS : "HH:mm:ss",
                L : "DD/MM/YYYY",
                LL : "D MMMM YYYY",
                LLL : "D MMMM YYYY LT",
                LLLL : "dddd, DD. MMMM YYYY"
            }
        };

moment.locale('de', moment_de);
```

Comment: I've tested in firefox and works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/tqrkLt2c/1/ note I changed März to Märzus to check it is using the JSON specified and for me it is working on Firefox, Chrome and even Internet Explorer

Comment: But when I set a default value it doesnt work, like I do here in my config: onOpen: function() {
                if(dataStartdate == "") {
                    this.setDate(moment().add({days: startDaysFromNow}).toDate());
                } else {
                    this.setDate(moment(dataStartdate).toDate());
                }
            },

Comment: But I agreee, with the alert() the correct langauge is shown, but not when I set a default value in the calendar or when I set a new date by clicking in the calendar.

Comment: could you please post your example in http://jsfiddle.net or similar? This way will be easy to reproduce your problem, and perhaps help you to solve it :)

Comment: In my fiddle it works...too bad for me http://jsfiddle.net/8hpe3dqu/15/

Comment: Well, if it works for you on Fiddle but not in your setup sound like you have on your code a really tiny bug preventing it to work. Hope you find it soon.

Comment: The problem is, when I load the site for the first time after clearing the cache, the correct language is shown. When I reload the site without clearing the cache, the wrong language is shown again and again until I clear again the cache...no idea what that could be the reason for.

Comment: That's really weird. Do you get the library from some CDN? Sound like some other process on your browser is getting your library so you are getting a wrong file. I't the only idea I have ...